# JpaRepository not saving entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have a server using spring boot and spring data jpa.

I have two classes annotated with `@RestController` in my server. One of them might change entities, while the other won't.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class ControllerA {
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    public ControllerA(EntityRepository entityRepository) {
        this.entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/pathStr")
    public void changeEntity(@RequestParam("entityId") Long entityId) {
        // init
        Entity entity = entityRepository.findById(entityId);
        // make changes to entity
        entity.getOneToOneLinkedEntity().setIntProperty(0);
        // save entity
        entityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class ControllerB {

    private Entity cachedEntity;
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    public ControllerB(EntityRepository entityRepository) {
        this.entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/otherPath")
    public void getEntity(ArgumentType argument) {
        if (cachedEntity == null) {
            cachedEntity = entityRepository.save(new Entity());
        }
        Entity entity = entityRepository.findById(cachedEntity.getId()).orElse(null);
        int properyValue = entity.getOneToOneLinkedEntity().getIntProperty(); // this is not zero
    }
}
```

Here are the two entities and the repository:

```
@Entity
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private OneToOneLinkedEntity linkedEntity;
}

@Entity
public class OneToOneLinkedEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private int intProperty = 0;
}

public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
}
```

I make a call to ControllerA.changeEntity from the client, and once that returns, I make another call to ControllerB.getEntity. The changes I made in the first call aren't shown in the second call, (**and they're not in the database either if I query directly with sql**) the int property has an old value. Even though I do the save only on the Entity and not on the linkedEntity, the `CascadeType.ALL` should make the the linked entity update too, right?

I tried adding an `entityRepository.flush()` after the save in ControllerA, but the issue still appears. What can I do? How can I make ControllerB get the correct value of intProperty?

This is what I have in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
```

Comment: The OneToOne annotation with cascade should be enough to make this work. Could you explain where the "cachedEntity" value comes from ?

Comment: @Raphael It's created on the first call to ControllerB.getEntity(). With something like: if (cachedEntity == null) {cachedEntity = entityRepository.save(new Entity());}. I'll add the code to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `@Transactional` annotation to your method, so spring will handle the transaction and commit your changes.
This usually comes on the `@Service` class, but I see in your example that you do not have one, so put it on the controller (or add service layer, I think it's better)

Comment: I tried adding @Transactional, both to the class and to the method, both the one from javax.transaction, and the one from org.springframework.transaction.annotation. I still don't see the changes in the database after calling `changeEntity`

Comment: Do I need to add something in application.properties?

Comment: try setting the auto-commit property to true

Comment: I don't really know this property, but I did some googling and tried these: spring.datasource.auto-commit,spring.jpa.hibernate.autocommit,
spring.jpa.hibernate.auto-commit,
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.autocommit,
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.auto-commit,
hibernate.connection.autocommit,
hibernate.connection.auto-commit. None worked

Comment: You were right, just adding @Transactional was enough. I made some stupid mistakes while changing the code to test that and it didn't work at first.

Comment: There are different @Transactional annotations. Which one do you mean? Please add your import to show what is actually needed.

Comment: Downvoted for not identifying import as judos suggests. When there are multiple providers for an annotation with a specific name, you need to identify the package it is associated. Annotation names are not unique within space and time. Even if "@Foobar" only has a single implementation today, it doesn't mean there wont be two more "@Foobar"s a year from now.

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring dependency injection which is the beauty of spring framework.

1. Make a Repository class which implements JPARepository and annotate it with @Repository.
2. Make a Service class and annotate it with @Service and @Transactional.
3. In Service class autowire the Repository and make corresponding methods call like .save() .find() etc.
4. In Controller Class autowire the service class and call service method which will call repository methods.

This is all you have to do.
For making your application flow fast, better you create model for the entity class and pass the model between classes instead of entity as it contains a lot more information and thus much more heavy than normal model object.

Comment: Repositories are automatically implemented by Spring Data JPA, so you don't have to implement them yourself.

Comment: Yea, but to make more methods you need to make a interface and can add abstract method in it, rest its implementation will be given be spring.